# Derived property never called

Tags: c#, xaml, properties, triggers

I want to set the `Visbility` of an `Expander` based on the selected value of a `ComboBox`.
That `ComboBox` is already mapped to an object from the `Model`:

```
<ComboBox Name="SelectedCar" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CarCategories}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Car.CarCategory, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I've set a property in the VM that derives the `Visbility` this way:

```
private Visibility _extraCarDetailsVisibility;
public Visibility ExtraCarDetailsVisibility
{
    get
    {
        if (ManagedPortfolioSelected != null)
        {
            var category = Car.CarCategory.ToLower();
            if (category == "porsche")
            {
                _extraCarDetailsVisibility= Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        _extraCarDetailsVisibility=  Visibility.Collapsed;
        return _extraCarDetailsVisibility;
    }
    set 
    { 
        _extraCarDetailsVisibility= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ExtraCarDetailsVisibility");
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
<Expander Visibility="{Binding Path=ExtraCarDetailsVisibility}">
```

However this doesn't work since I think the `CarCategories` change event isn't subscribed (and it seems I cannot really as it comes from the Model) so the `ExtraCarDetailsVisibility` property is never recalled when I cahnge the Car Category...

How would you do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was couple of issues there:

1. I was missing to inherit from the INotifyPropertyChanged in my ICar interface although implemented in the Car object - so couln't reach the PropertyChanged event there.
2. I had to update the code in order to fire an event each time my ComboBox Catgory was changed. To do so, I hadto:

Hook some event to the PropertyChanged event of the Car object:

> ```
>     private ICar _carSelected;
>     public IPortfolio CarSelected
>     {
>         get { return _carSelected; }
>         set
>         {
>             if (_carSelected!= value)
>             {
>                 if (_carSelected!= null)
>                 {
>                     _carSelected.PropertyChanged -= OnCarSelectedPropertyChanged;
>                 }
>                 _carSelected= value;
>                 // Also subscribing to any change that happens to the Carselected
>                 _carSelected.PropertyChanged += OnCarSelectedPropertyChanged;
>             }
>             // Notifying when the selected portfolio is changed
>             NotifyPropertyChanged("CarSelected");
>         }
>     }
> ```

Trigger the event once the CarSelected property changes:

```
void OnCarSelectedPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)    
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "CarCategory")
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ExtraCarDetailsVisibility");
    }
}
```

... that will then update my visibility property I've hooked to the View:

```
    private Visibility _extraCarDetailsVisibility;
    public Visibility ExtraCarDetailsVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            _extraCarDetailsVisibility= Visibility.Collapsed;
            if (PendingCarSelected != null)
            {
                var category = CarSelected.CounterpartyCategory.ToLower();
                if (category == "porsche" || category == "porsches")
                {
                    _extraCarDetailsVisibility= Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
            return _extraCarDetailsVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            _extraCarDetailsVisibility= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ExtraCarDetailsVisibility");
        }
    }
```